# Quais os motivos para escolher entre camelCase e PascalCase em nomes de métodos?

Tags: característica-linguagem, método, estilo-de-codificação, ux, design-de-linguagem

Primeiro, não estou querendo saber o que você gosta mais ou o que usa na sua linguagem, quero saber a motivação para escolher um ou outro padrão em uma linguagem hipotética.

Segundo, isto é um pouco estilo de codificação, que na verdade você deve seguir o padrão que a linguagem adotou, mas principalmente sobre porque uma linguagem adotaria assim. Não é sobre uma linguagem existente, vou as citar para exemplificar o que quero.

Um exemplo bem típico é o Java ter adotado camelCase e o C# adotou o PascalCase. Eu tenho um *bias* hoje para o PascalCase, não sei bem porque mas assim que vi o PascalCase fez muito sentido pra mim, mesmo tendo adotado camelCase antes em outras linguagens. Mas meio que só C# o adotou. Eu olho aquilo e sinto que está melhor padronizado, parece algo da estrutura do código e diferencia da variável que faz parte do algoritmo.

Meio que todo mundo adotou o PascalCase para nomes de tipos e até de *namespaces*. Em C# não diferencia nada para o método, mas são contextos diferentes, o IDE coloca cor adequada. Java, JS, e outras preferiram deixar claro que é um método de uma forma diferente, ao mesmo tempo que confunde com nomes de variáveis, exceto pelos parenteses que quase sempre é usado, mas não em todos casos. No começo Java nunca tinha essa confusão, hoje tem, JS tinha como confundir, mas não foi uma linguagem bem pensada (PHP tem um pouco das duas coisas, não confundia no começo e não foi bem pensada, ela nem respeita sempre isso). C# nasceu sabendo que isto poderia ser confuso.

Eu gosto da ideia do camelCase, mas parece feio (é bem subjetivo mesmo). Considero isto um aspecto da UX do programador e por isso considerando o *design* de linguagem, porque escolher o estilo padrão não deixa de fazer parte desta disciplina, então queria **entender a motivação de uso de cada um**.

Comment: Conheço uma linguagem que ficaria triste porque não considerou a *snake_case* na pergunta.

Comment: Mas pode falar dele :) Esse eu odeio com todas as forças e já sei porque :P

Comment: é uma pergunta que remete muitas opiniões, porque se a linguagem como exemplo `C#` te fornece um estilo (ela indica pela IDE mas, nada que não possa ser desabilitado) e você não quer seguir esse estilo, não tem obrigação e pode ser escolhido a sua maneira, o importante é se começou de um jeito que faça sempre do mesmo jeito.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic a pergunta não é sobre isso, é sobre a justificativa plausível e fundamentada de decisão de escolher um ou outro estilo, por isso não tem opinião, é o porquê de fazer um ou outro. https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/486/101

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Perceba que a pergunta não é "qual estilo devo usar", mas sim "quais são os parâmetros considerados que levam uma linguagem a adotar um determinado estilo". A resposta não depende da opinião de quem está perguntando ou respondendo.

Comment: @Maniero `é sobre a justificativa plausível e fundamentada de decisão de escolher um ou outro estilo` o estilo é geral (para todas as programação que fizer) ou o estilo é mediante linguagens (parece amplo e a indagação porque citou na pergunta linguagens)?

Comment: Para dar exemplos de diferenças existentes hoje e mostrar que há basicamente duas escolhas principais. A pergunta é sobre qualquer linguagem, não sobre uma ou algumas específicas, na verdade é sobre uma possível futura linguagem hipotética, pegando o comentário do Anderson, é sobre os parâmetros as se considerar para escolher um estilo ou outro se você for criar uma linguagem e for estabelecer na API básica dela e guia de estilo. A pergunta é sobre *design* de linguagem e não sobre as existentes. É sobre a motivação para dar melhor experiência do programador quando vai codificar.

Comment: É uma pergunta intrigante. Eu conheço uma pessoa que detesta com todas as forças tanto um quanto outro e sempre tende a usar _snake_case_ ou _kebab-case_ (vi esse nome no SO agora pouco) — como é usado em Lisp e derivados — sob a premissa de que é a leitura fica muito mais simples e "natural".

Comment: @LINQ A resposta não precisa fica presa só nesses dois, quem sabe até falando de outra forma possa indicar um caminho (desde que não seja só a pessoa falando porque gosta)

Comment: relacionado https://github.com/ktaranov/naming-convention/blob/master/C%23%20Coding%20Standards%20and%20Naming%20Conventions.md e https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/xzf533w0(v=vs.71) explicam o porque de algumas questões

Comment: @VirgilioNovic não achei nada que explicasse a decisão. Dizer que é pra ser consistente com o .NET não ajuda nada, porque a pergunta é justamente porque é adotado assim, e não que convenção alguém adotou. De qualquer forma a pergunta não é sobre o que o C# adotou e sim porque uma linguagem deveria adotar uma forma ou outra. Pode ser que coincidentemente o C# ou outra linguagem tenha tomado uma decisão com base em algum critério e ele sirva como boa explicação, mas não é o foco da pergunta entender nada se uma linguagem específica, isto é colateral. Obrigado pelos *links*.

Comment: Então a sua pergunta não vai ter uma resposta digna, já visto que quem criou isso fica complicado a gente falar com ele para perguntar **porque foi feito assim**.Esses links são referencia do site oficial e independente de qualquer coisa não tem divulgação do porque mas, tem alguns pontos por isso "relacionado" e não como razão principal, mas, eu já tenho a conclusão que essa pergunta infelizmente não trará as respostas, não adianta fazer uma pergunta tão ampla dessa, deveria sim ser divididas em linguagens (que já seria muita coisa) cada uma segue um filosofia e até vi cultura em muitos links

Comment: Se a pessoa entender sobre *design* de linguagem terá. Novamente, a pergunta não é sobre a decisão que alguém tomou, e sim sobre porque tomar essa decisão, independe de alguém ter tomado a decisão de uma determinada forma. Mesmo que ninguém tenha tomado pode tomar agora, desde que tenha uma explicação plausível, desde que a pessoa exponha as vantagens e desvantagens de cada um, que tenha uma informação que mostre um motivo, como o hugo fez, ainda que não de forma completa. Você está com a ideia fixa que eu quero saber de cada linguagem, não é isso que eu pedi.

Comment: Eu entendi depois do penúltimo comentário que você quer as razões, os porquês. Pra mim a sua pergunta é boa, mas, é ampla tem que se levar em conta muitos aspectos.

Comment: Vou ressaltar também a abordagem do Go, que torna público os membros que começam com caractere capitalizado. Não é específico ao `PascalCase`, mas acaba sendo a convenção adotada. Os em `camelCase`, por consequência, ficam privados. Apesar disso, acho curioso a pergunta não ter incluído o `snake_case`, que acaba sendo adotado por linguagens como Rust. Eu pessoalmente acho o `snake_case` o mais fácil de ler, embora peque com maior quantidade de caracteres consumidos, dificultando o enquadramento em monitores menores. Acho que no fim é uma mera questão de opinião do designer mesmo.

Answer (score 16):

**Primeiro um pouco de história**

Essa resposta é baseada nesse excelente artigo do Celso Kitamura https://celsokitamura.com.br/pascal-case-e-camel-case/

Em 1813 Jacob Berzelius, químico, sugeriu uma convenção para formaliza a forma de escrever as fórmulas químicas. Ele propôs indicar cada elemento químico por um símbolo de uma ou duas letras, sendo a primeira em maiúscula. Veja o Exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No exemplo da fórmula `NaCl` teríamos `SódioCloro` = *Cloreto de sódio*, mesmo naquela época não havia um conceito único para escrever fórmulas químicas, e essa proposta foi adotada para normalizar a escrita, e posteriormente acabou virou regra. Foi algo que facilitou a vida do usuário, pois gera menos erros e é de fácil compreensão e utilização na hora de escrever fórmulas e elementos.

Essa é a convenção adotada na tabela periódica, e que posteriormente foi aplicada em outros meios como na programação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os pontos cardeais por sua vez utilizam de outra convenção por exemplo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ainda entre as décadas de 70 e 80 não existia bem um padrão, por N motivos, vou tentar aborda-los em outro momento. Mas o que se viu foi o Camel Case ou Pascal Case serem adotados culturalmente, e apesar de não ser regra são incentivados.

> No caso do .NET, a Microsoft recomenda:
>
> - Usar **Pascal Case** para todos os nomes de membros, tipos e namespace públicos que consistem em várias palavras.
>   *PropertyDescriptor*
>   *HtmlTag*
> - Usar **Camel Case** para nomes de parâmetros.
>   *propertyDescriptor*
>   *htmlTag*

Aqui tem uma lista com o `Naming_Convention` de vária linguagens, para refletir no que elas têm em comum, prós e contras, etc. (C e C++, Java, JavaScript, .NET, PHP, Python, Ruby, etc.): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)

- Fornecer informações adicionais (ou seja, metadados) sobre o uso para o qual um identificador é colocado;
- Ajudar a formalizar expectativas e promover consistência dentro de uma equipe de desenvolvimento;
- Permitir o uso de ferramentas automatizadas de refatoração ou pesquisa e substituição com potencial mínimo de erro;
- Aumentar a clareza em casos de potencial ambiguidade;
- Para melhorar a aparência estética e profissional do produto de trabalho (por exemplo, desaprovando nomes excessivamente longos, nomes - Cômicos ou "fofinhos" ou abreviações);
- Para ajudar a evitar "colisões de nomenclatura" que podem ocorrer quando o produto de trabalho de diferentes organizações é combinado (consulte também: namespaces);
- Fornecer dados significativos para serem usados ​​em transferências de projetos que requeiram o envio do código-fonte do programa e toda a documentação relevante;
- Para fornecer melhor entendimento em caso de reutilização de código após um longo intervalo de tempo.

**Uma palavra é uma chave**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare como a variação de altura da linha ascendente entre maiúscula é minúscula cria um pattern visual, que pode ser usado para reconhecer facilmente as palavras. Esse variação na frequência das letras ajuda o olho a reconhecer padrões e palavras de forma mais rápida. Já quando esta tudo em CAIXA ALTA, a linha não varia, fica reta, e para reconhecermos a palavra precisamos realmente ler com mais atenção.

```
var UmaChaveUtil //(3 variações de Case)
var umaChaveUtil //(2 variações de Case)
```

*Uma "chave" com mais variações de "segredo" pode ser mais útil e melhor para o reconhecimento de maneira geral...* (falarei mais disso abaixo)

---

**Além das convenções - *Aspectos tipográficos e de UX***

Independente da linguagem outros pontos devem ser levados em consideração. Por exemplo, qual a dificuldade de se escrever PalavrasLongasEmCamelCase? Qual a leiturabilidade disso? Em um mundo de palavras é mais fácil reconhecer `UmaPalavra` ou `umaPalavra`. A escaneabilidade é muito importante na hora de identificar palavras específicas no meio de outras. E nesse artigo do NNGroup existem boas pistas das práticas que você pode adotar e que vão apresentar uma melhor UX https://www.nngroup.com/articles/glanceable-fonts/.

Independente de ser adotado Camel ou Pascal o sistema é `case sensitive`? Usar essas regras vão resultar em mais erros ou menos erros, é mais fácil de escrever ou de ler? Para um sistema que ainda não existe, considere fazer um Teste A/B. As palavras reservadas pode seguir uma convenção, já as classes que são nome próprio podem ter outra... Então até mesmo uma Pesquisa Qualitativa pode ser interessante nessa faze, algo que é muito comum de se fazer em UX e Design Thinking.

> **4° Lei da heurística:** Os usuários não devem se perguntar se palavras, situações ou ações diferentes significam a mesma coisa.

Quando se fala em heurística o principal fator talvez seja a consistência, então ter regras claras evita erros e deixa o usuário mais confortável. Então ao definir uma regra, evite deixar que coisas como essa sejam válidas, pois além de não ter coerência, pode ser ambíguo e confundir o usuário.

*Fonte:* https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Repare novamente na imagem acima*. Será que o usuário poderia entende "Calendário" de forma diferente que "calendário"? Não posso afirmar, mas pode ser que as pessoas entendam isso de forma diferente, um calendário pode ser um calendário qualquer, já o Calendário, pode ser o App de Calendário.

**Proeminência Visual**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare na imagem acima, veja como um título com *Cases* variados parece se destacar mais do que o outro só com a letra inicial maiúscula.

*Fonte:* https://medium.com/@jsaito/making-a-case-for-letter-case-19d09f653c98

**Um pouco de opinião**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando você pensa em sistemas, as palavras reservadas ou palavras padrão da linguagem, ou que se repetem a todo o momento e são iguais para todos, poderiam ser "mais discretas", já as `variáveis` ou `classes` (como no CSS), que são palavras que o usuário "inventa" (e que cada um pode escrever de um jeito), você poderia definir regras claras. Pois como são palavras concebidas  pelo próprio usuário regras poderiam ser melhor que boas práticas. Essa seria uma maneira de normalizar a escrita independente de quem escreve. No CSS `.classe` é diferente de `.Classe`, mas os dois funcionam... Isso é bom ou ruim? Logicamente depende, mas se só fosse permitido uma das formas poderia ser melhor para o usuário. O usuário gosta de seguir padrões, e o olho aprende a achar padrões... E o Pascal Case pode ser um padrão mais fácil para o usuário identificar palavras não originais da linguagem (palavras que são definidas por outros usuários). Mas como falei, mais pesquisas e testes devem ser feitos.

Exemplo de tabela com regras claras:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Gestalt**

Quando se fala em "reconhecimento de padrão" lembre-se que **nem tudo que vemos estamos na verdade lendo**. Um dos princípios da Gestalt é o reconhecimento de formas. O olho humano e o cérebro sempre tendem e reconhecer formas e padrões. E isso pode ser fundamental para a escaneabilidade do código. É como um artifício que pode auxiliar a reconhecer rapidamente palavras no meio do texto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Como nosso cérebro utiliza parâmetros de leitura visual, ao enxergarmos um composto de elementos (sejam eles objetos, pessoas, paisagens, animais ou textos), a tendência é agrupar características que sejam semelhantes, de forma que sua interpretação seja a mais rápida possível.

*Fonte:*  https://whitecom.com.br/8-principios-da-gestalt/

Wiki da Gestalt: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gestalt

> Embora seja sabido há algum tempo que o texto de tamanho maior é mais legível, este estudo mostrou que o peso e o processo também são importantes. As letras minúsculas exigiam 26% mais tempo para leitura precisa do que letras maiúsculas, e o texto condensado exigia 11,2% mais tempo do que o normal. Também houve efeitos significativos de interação entre o caso e o tamanho, sugerindo que os efeitos negativos das letras minúsculas são exacerbados com pequenos tamanhos de fonte.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Antigamente as IDEs, Terminais e Prompts não eram tão customizáveis, eles tinham um `font-size` padrão assim como um `font-family` padrão, e cor. Tudo foi pensado para o usuário ter uma melhor experiencia. Então as escolhes tipográfica também estão ligadas a forma como você vai escrever. Já é comprovado que textos longos [não devem ser escritos todo em maiúsculo](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0042698907002830?via%3Dihub), assim como fontes mais "condensadas" são mais difíceis de serem lidas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare no formato dos "shapes" veja como o UpperCase é mais difícil de identificar o caractere, principalmente pela "falta" de contraste por não ter descendentes (`p`) e ascendentes (`d`) na `base-line` e `caps-line`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja como uma fonte com a "Altura de X" pequena é mais difícil de perceber a diferença entre Upper e Lower case *(a primeira fonte tem o `X Height` menor)*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Auto regulamentação**

Mas quando a linguagem é livre o que se vê é o surgimento de convenções, seja de escrita ou de organização, como é o caso do `CSS` e suas metodologias de nomenclatura como `OOCSS`, `SMACSS`, `BEM`, `DRY`. Site com alguns exemplos e definições https://tableless.com.br/oocss-smacss-bem-dry-css-afinal-como-escrever-css/ vale dizer que para cada uma delas existem prós e contras, mas escolhendo um padrão regras devem ser seguidas, mesmo em uma "linguagem" que não tem regras :)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**E no Mobile?**

Já pensou como pode ser cansativo escrever variando entre maiúsculas em minúsculas em um dispositivo Mobile? Ainda mais com o corretor ortográfico tentando transforma o camelCase toda hora? Esse é um ambiente que certamente teria que ser estudado para avaliar o que seria mais fácil e produtivo para o usuário trabalhar. Não achei dada que se refira ao assunto, mas talvez o *kebab-case* (palavras com hifenização) sejam mais fácil de digitar no celular.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Então todas essas escolhas podem influenciar na UX e na escolha do que adotar...

Livro recomendado **Design-Time Web Usability Evaluation with Guideliner**: https://site-109191.mozfiles.com/files/109191/2228-7961-1-SM.pdf

**OBS 1:** O artigo do NNGroup citado acima feito com palavras "avulsas" e não em textos corridos. Ele não aborda especificadamente Camel Case ou Pascal Case, e inclusive sugere que se façam mais estudos.

**OBS 2:** Não abordei no assunto, mas pense também qual dos dois estilos seria mais interessantes para os Dislexos. Pensando em acessibilidade e inclusão seria legal ter mais informações e levar em conta como uma pessoa com dislexia ou TDAH interagem com esses tipos.

Comment: A introdução é muito boa porque não sabia disto, depois sobre a documentação do .NET não achei que adicionou nada relevante porque não é o foco da pergunta, a parte mais importante onde fala do que interessa é promissora, ainda estou digerindo. Tudo faz sentido, mas note que houve uma escolha diferente para variáveis, métodos, e tipos, só pra dizer os itens que considero mais importantes e sua explicação não considera essas diferentes, note que a pergunta tem a ver com método (eu entendo um pouco melhor a escolha pra variável e tipo).

Comment: A questão do *case sensitive* aí não importa para a questão, mas vamos dizer que é. A ideia do teste A/B é padrão pra UX e de fato deveria ser feita para a escolha, a dúvida é justamente se fizeram antes que eu possa aproveitar ou concluíram algo mesmo que empiricamente. Inclusive imagino que tudo foi pensado para usar sem IDE de forma legível. pena que a análise final não é sobre os dois estilos. Ainda estou avaliando mais.

Comment: @Maniero sem querer dar desculpinhas rss, mas é que eu tenho um conhecimento muito superficial das abstrações da programação, assim como o que seriam métodos, classes etc... Tentei contribuir com o conhecimento que tenho sobre Tipografia e UX. Acho que quando surge uma linguagem (algo raro), assim como o FW JS por exemplo, os autores hj tem muito mais acesso a pesquisas e testes para avaliar o que seria mais adequado. Imagine em um ambiente Mobile, como seria chato ficar alternando entre o Upper e Lowers, e para piorar imagine o corretor ortográfico mudando o que vc escreve...

Comment: @Maniero Uma das eurística mais importantes é a consistência. Então o importante é que não seja algo "cada um faz como gostar", seria mais indicado manter um padrão. Agora qual padrão escolher vc pode decidir estudando sua persona, o ambiente dela e tendo empatia.

Comment: Pior que eu acho que eles não têm :D Caso contr´rio seria fácil achar algo sobre isso, eu acho que eles escolhem porque gostavam assim. O pessoal do C# deve ter um motivo bom, mas só suponho. Porque o C# e .NET nasceram de uma implementação real do Java, pra eles mudarem tudo devem ter um motivo. Não quero nem saber o motivo deles, mas sim o motivo geral, que por coincidência pode ser o deles. A resposta é boa, instrutiva, ainda não tenho certeza se ela responde ao que quero. Sobre a consistência eu sei, até já escrevi várias vezes sobre isso. E não é questão de qual escolher, mas porque.

Comment: @Maniero esse é um assunto mais profundo do que parece, espero que apareçam outros dispostos a contribuir e que tragam algo que possa ser mais "definitivo" ou mais concreto pelo menos []´s