# Definir variáveis com letra maiúscula em Python

Tags: python, variáveis

Bom, estou aprendendo python e de vez em quando vou ler códigos de outros dev's para aprender algo e surge variáveis com letras maiúsculas.

**Exemplos:** `RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES = [500, 502, 503, 504]`, `MAX_RETRIES = 10`

Minha pergunta é, em que momento eu deveria usar variáveis desse tipo? Grato desde já.

Comment: Não é específico para Python mas pode ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/386953/101 Na verdade dada a qualidade baixa da pergunta eu acho até que a resposta ali é o melhor que pode obter. Também https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/160947/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/239964/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/243958/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geralmente, as variáveis de letra maiúsculas são "constantes", ou seja, uma variável cujo valor não é alterado na execução. Em Python, não é obrigatório utilizar variáveis de letra maiúscula para isso, mas muitos desenvolvedores utilizam porque em muitas linguagens isto é uma convenção de código ou regra como por exemplo: Java e Ruby.

Essa forma de criar variáveis também é utilizado por desenvolvedores quando querem, por exemplo, definir a configuração de algo. Veja estes dois simples exemplos abaixo:

## Primeiro exemplo:

```
class Conta(object):

    PESSOA_FISICA = 1
    PESSOA_JURIDICA = 2

    def __init__(self,tipo):

        if tipo == Banco.PESSOA_FISICA:
            print("Você entrou com uma conta de pessoa física.")

        elif tipo == Banco.PESSOA_JURIDICA:
            print("Você entrou com uma conta de pessoa jurídica.")

        else:
            raise ValueError('O parâmetro "tipo" deve ser PESSOA_FISICA ou PESSOA_JURIDICA')
```

## Segundo exemplo:

```
import pygame

WINDOW_GEOMETRY = [800,400]
WINDOW_TITLE = "Example"

pygame.display.set_mode( WINDOW_GEOMETRY )
pygame.display.set_caption( WINDOW_TITLE )
```

Enfim, quase sempre que você ver uma variável totalmente maiúscula você já sabe que ela se trata de uma constante e que ela certamente serve para ser usada em alguma configuração.